# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyHook'

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, import, pyhook

I'm trying to use pyHook 1.5.1 on Windows with python 3.6. I successfully installed the module using pip and have confirmed that it is present in the site-packages folder with the rest of my modules. However, when I try to import it, I recieve the error mentioned in the title of the question.

Is there another step I have to take to get pyHook working? Or is there more information I could provide to determine if I performed the install incorrectly?

code:

```
import pyHook
```

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-22-d2003ef65f38>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Alec/pyHookTest.py', wdir='C:/Users/Alec')

  File "C:\Users\Alec\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Alec\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Alec/pyHookTest.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pyHook

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyHook'
```

Comment: Do you also have Python2 installed?  you might need to install with `pip3 pyhook` to make it available to Python 3.

Comment: I do have python2, but I get the same error. My understanding was that with python3.6, pip3 is just pip

Answer (score 0):

When opening [PyHook's Pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/pyHook/) there isn't the `pip install` which seems to indicate that `pip install PyHook` won't work.

An alternative to install it is downloading the file from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook). Make sure one downloads the file that corresponds to one's computer (either 32/64).

If one is not familiar with [whl files](https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing.html), one may need to install wheel, as

```
pip install wheel
```

And then

```
wheel install file_name.whl
```